# Child process maximum limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, child-process

I want to compute the size of folder (i used readdirp module). For large folder the operation blocks my main thread so my **electron** application hangs.

So i moved size computation process to forked child.

since i have array of folders, i looping and forking new child process, on every iteration.

> These child Nodes are still whole new instances of V8. Assume at least
>   30ms startup and 10mb memory for each new Node. That is, you cannot
>   create many thousands of them. I have studied somewhere.

1. so how to manage this forking process ?

**NOTE : After completion of computation in child, i sended the result details to parent using IPC (process.send)**

Can i able to make use of cluster module for this operation, if that how ?.

Comment: Create one child process. You won't increase speed with more processes.

Comment: @JonasWilms,  can i able to make use of cluster