# Confusion on how cluster and child Process works

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have used child process in my electron application. and I forked child process only after the previous child process ends. And also if I fork multiple processes, it won't increase the speed.

so can I able to use the cluster module in electron application to fork multiple child processes at the same time.

```
let doneFunction = {}
let queue = createQueue(1);
this.state.files.forEach((file, i) => {
    queue.defer(function(details, done) {
        readSizeRecursive(details.path, e); // inside that i forked child
        doneFunction = done;
    }, file);
});

childFinished = () => {
    doneFunction()
}
```

I previously asked [Child process maximum limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946574/child-process-maximum-limit?noredirect=1#comment100432626_56946574) but I can't any answer.

1. if I forked two cluster means, and I fork two child process means, each child runs parallel in two different clusters?

Comment: Take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942555/does-the-electron-framework-allow-multi-threading-through-web-workers.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with all that forking and parallelising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And also if I fork multiple processes, it won't increase the speed.

To increase the speed, you need to speed up the bottleneck which is disk IO in your case(directory size calculation etc...). CPU is much faster than disk IO, therefore multi/single threads/processes just do not matter.

> if I forked two cluster means, and I fork two child process means, each child runs parallel in two different clusters?

yes, but it will not speed up your final result as mentioned above

Comment: This is the right answer. The problem is slow Disk.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a better understanding of cluster mode from this article 
[Cluster definition in depth](http://www.acuriousanimal.com/2017/08/12/understanding-the-nodejs-cluster-module.html)

But I personally recommended to use `Nginx` for such things.
[Take a look in NgInx](https://www.nginx.com/)

I hope it helps. happy Coding :)